# Get root dimension on profound child measure event

Tags: android, android-layout

In the view hierarchy:

```
Window > ViewGroup (root) > ViewGroup[...] > View (child)
```

I need to know root dimension in a profound child `onMeasure` event.

Exemple:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int wMS, int hMS) {
    int desiredW = Math.round(rootW * factorW);
    int desiredH = Math.round(rootH * factorH);
    /* ... compute final dimensions ... */
    setMeasuredDimension(finalW, finalH);
}
```

Note: At this moment, `getRootView` and `getWindow` dimentions equals to 0 because children have to `setMeasuredDimention` before their parents

Considering a lot of children needing this dimension, to do it:

- I created an interface:

  ```
  public interface OnRootSizeChanged {
      public void onRootSizeChanged(int w, int h);
  }
  ```
- I implemented my child which now implements `OnRootSizeChanged` inteface:

  ```
  private int rootW;
  private int rootH;
  @Override
  public void onRootSizeChanged(int w, int h) {
      rootW = w;
      rootH = h;
  }
  ```
- I implemented root view:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int wMS, int hMS) {
      int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(wMS);
      int h = MeasureSpec.getSize(hMS);
      dispatchOnRootSizeChange(this, w, h);
      super.onMeasure(wMS, hMS);
  }
  private void dispatchOnRootSizeChange(ViewGroup v, int w, int h) {
      for (int i = 0, n = v.getChildCount(); i < n; i++) {
          View child = v.getChildAt(i);
          if (child instanceof OnRootSizeChanged)
              ((OnRootSizeChanged) child).onRootSizeChanged(w, h);
          if (child instanceof ViewGroup)
              dispatchOnRootSizeChange((ViewGroup) child, w, h);
      }
  }
  ```

My question is:

- Have I simpler way to do this without recursivity or with better practice ?

---

Update: This method is invalid in case of `ViewPager` element in ViewGroup[...] breabcrumb. When `ViewPager` instantiate children pages, they have not yet received `OnRootSizeChanged` event so:

- Children have to ask the root dimension, no the root to tell his dimension to their children

So I searched how to target root from a profound child to ask him:

- `getRootView()` not seems targeting the view attached with `setContentView()`
- `getWindow().getDecorView()` either

One possible way is:

- On child:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int wMS, int hMS) {
      ViewParent parent = getParent();
      while (parent instanceof RootViewClass == false)
          parent = parent.getParent();
      RootViewClass root = (RootViewClass) parent;
      int desiredW = Math.round(root.w * factorW);
      int desiredH = Math.round(root.h * factorH);
      /* ... compute final dimensions ... */
      setMeasuredDimension(finalW, finalH);
  }
  ```
- On root instance of `RootViewClass`:

  ```
  public int w, h;
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int wMS, int hMS) {
      w = MeasureSpec.getSize(wMS);
      h = MeasureSpec.getSize(hMS);
      super.onMeasure(wMS, hMS);
  }
  ```

But with lot of children, I don't think this is a good practice. If I could find root view without use of loop.

Comment: Why can't you simply use the loop? The view hierarchy depth should be small and you should get the reference to the parent in other place **once** so you don't do the loop each time `onMeasure()` gets called.

Comment: That's what I would do if I do not find another solution but I have the feeling that this is not a good practice. Also, perhaps there is a simpler and more relevant solution I ignore? that is the object of my question

Comment: You're trying to see what constraints does the parent have from within a child, this isn't a good practice also. I don't see any other way, but than again you don't need the loop, you just need in those child views a reference to the root(which you'll get a at the activity level so you only look for it once), root which will store each time the last constraints to have them available for the children.

Comment: To that you better understand my goal, I develop a resizable application which must adapt to the size of the window. All the UI must always be visible to the user (as an openGL game for multi-screen sizes), the scrollable View for little window doesn’t interest me, I need to scale all the View. So all my elements depends of my root View dimensions. In most of case, I use parent dimensions to calculate children dimensions, but in certain cases, I need to recover the root dimension origin. May be I am engaging in a wrong way? If you have some tips, I will be very recognizing

Comment: Why not make the root layout a custom one? If all the UI controls must be visible then this root view will impose fixed dimensions on its children(which will further propagate them to their children) based on the current dimensions.

Comment: My root layout is already a custom ViewGroup, I'm afraid I do not understand your suggestion... When the window is resized, the root View define the first degree of children Views dimensions, in major cases, it's parents which define children dimensions, but in certain case, children have to know the origin root dimension, to uniform text sizes in px for example depending of root width & height

Comment: This is what I meant https://gist.github.com/luksprog/9608138 See if it helps in any way.

Comment: Nice way, please answer my question to receive your deserved bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward the parent's size by storing those values in the `onMeasure()` method as you receive them and then letting the children access the values in their `onMeasure()` method through the `Context` reference:

```
// simple interface
public interface ParentRef {
   void YourViewGroup getRoot();
}

// the Activity implements the interface above
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements ParentRef {

   private YourViewGroup mRoot;

   //in onCreate initialize the mRoot reference

   @Override
   public YourViewGroup getRoot() {
      return mRoot;
   }
   //... rest of the Activity
}

// the custom ViewGroup will store the dimensions:
//fields in the root view
private int mCurWidth;
private int mCurHeight;

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int wMS, int hMS) {
    int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(wMS);
    int h = MeasureSpec.getSize(hMS);
    mCurWidth = w;
    mCurHeight = h;
    // now as the children are measured they can see the values above
    super.onMeasure(wMS, hMS);
}

public int getStoredWidth() {
    return mCurWidth;
}

public int getStoredHeight() {
    return mCurHeight;
}


// in the children's onMeasure simply do:
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int wMS, int hMS) {
   final YourViewGroup root = ((ParentRef) getContext()).getRoot();
   //width root.getStoredWidth()
   // height root.getStoredHeight()
   /* ... compute final dimensions ... */
   setMeasuredDimension(finalW, finalH);
}
```

Comment: I do not accept your answer now because I want to search a simpler way but I thank you for your interest of my question and this interesting way

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **ViewTreeObserver** (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html)

```
//...get your view, than attach a viewTreeObserver on it!
ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
       //misure the view here, like view.getHeight()
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however there is 2 main problems: I have not method to target the root view easily (my principal problem) and I need to define the child measure in OnMeasure event, OnLayout being called after OnMeasure.

Comment: Got it. What about this trick: the first time that a child executes the loop (and find the rootView), it attaches a tag (setTag)on the direct parent (or to each ancestor through the all path to the root). In this way, the second time that a child try to get the root, it first check the tag and if it is != null, it has the root without looping.